# cannot use specification in findAll method in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa

i'm trying to use specification in my repository findAll method but i get this message :

```
Cannot resolve method 'findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification<com.package.business.Eleve>)'
```

this is my specification class :

```
public class EleveSpecification {

    public static Specification<Eleve> nomIsLike(final String nom) {

        return new Specification<Eleve>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Eleve> personRoot, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                String likePattern = getLikePattern(nom);
                return cb.like(cb.lower(personRoot.<String>get(Eleve_.nom)), likePattern);
            }

            private String getLikePattern(final String nom) {
                StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
                pattern.append(nom.toLowerCase());
                pattern.append("%");
                return pattern.toString();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and I use JUnit to test my specification :

```
@org.junit.Test
    public void findByNom() {
        List<Eleve> eleves = eleveRepository.findAll(EleveSpecification.nomIsLike("yassine"));

        //System.out.print(eleve.getNom());
        for (Eleve eleve : eleves) {
            System.out.print("" + eleve.getNom() + "  " + eleve.getPrenom());
        }

    }
```

This is my repository interface :

```
public interface EleveRepository extends JpaRepository<Eleve, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: Please post your Repository interface (including the extends paremter)

Comment: I added my repo interface but i don't think that the problem come from there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your repository needs to be :

```
public interface EleveRepository extends JpaRepository<Eleve, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Eleve> {

}
```